Collected user data using Django form aren't displayed in the target URL as planned
I've got the same problem as in 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/79063022/22401844', user data doesn't seem to be displayed as planned in the target URL. These are the codes used:
This is the view.py code:
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms

# Item list
items = ['earbuds', 'rollerblades', 'camera']

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.CharField(label='Product', max_length=50)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'card/card.html', {
        'items': items,
    })

def order(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.cleaned_data['product']
            items.append(product)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('card:carditems'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'card/order.html', {
                'form': form,
            })
    
    return render(request, 'card/order.html', {
        'form': OrderForm()
    })


This is the order.html where the user will fill in his order:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Order Here</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'card:carditems' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

And this is the card.html code which handle the added orders display:
{% extends 'card/layout0.html'%}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Card Items</h2>
    <ul>
       {% for item in items %}
            <li> {{ item }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}

And this is the urls.py code :
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = "card"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='carditems'),
    path('order/', views.order, name='order')
]

I tried the same solution suggested in my similar previous problem but it didn't work.

The problem is with action attr of your html, you sending request to carditems. It's a views.index view. But you need to send request to views.order view. So just change attr of your actions:
<form action="{% url 'card:order' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Also I would suggest to render form items by form.as_p for better look

That actually worked very well! Thanks a lot for your help.
